# PDO : How to execute a dynamic array of values?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, pdo

I am trying to execute a dynamic array of values with PDO, here is my PHP code:

```
protected function insertData($data, $table) {
    $db = $this->getDB();

    $columns = '';
    $params  = '';
    $values  = '';

    // Retrieves columns, their respective value and params.
    $i = 0;
    foreach($data as $col => $val) {
        $i++;
        $columns .= $i != count($data) ? "`$col`, " : "`$col`";
        $params  .= $i != count($data) ? "?, "      : "?";
        $values  .= $i != count($data) ? "'$val', " : "'$val'";
    }

    $query     = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($params)";
    $prepQuery = $db->prepare($query);
    return $prepQuery->execute([$values]);
}
```

When I execute this code, I get this error : "Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in".

I know the issue is that `$prepQuery->execute([$values])` actually does `$prepQuery->execute(["'val1', 'val2', 'val3'..."])` instead of what I wanna do which is `$prepQuery->execute(['val1', 'val2', 'val3'...])` but I don't know how to fix it...

How can I execute a dynamic array of values with PDO? The method is generic.

Thanks in advance, I hope I was clear enough. :/

Comment: Use implode `$str = implode("",$arr);` or str_replace

Comment: Or just build an array instead of a comma separated string

Comment: The wrong algorithm aside, your code is prone to **SQL injection**!

Comment: @YourCommonSense why does it prone to SQL injection? Btw the insertData() method can only be called if the data is OK (it is verified in another method in my controller). 
But I have to admit I don't have much knowledge in security and SQL injections so yeah

Do you have a better algorithm?


Thanks everyone tho

Comment: Obviously, because you are adding untreated variables to the SQL query. Just like *any* SQL injection works.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh of course I do it in other files and the SQL query is the final thing that is executed if everything went well before

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 lmao thank you indeed that was so obvious I feel so stupid now thank you so much

Comment: Other files have nothing to do with this code. It is like to put a bulletproof door to your house and keep all windows with wooden shades.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but the thing is I don't see how there could be an SQL injection since no SQL can be executed unless the $data array contains correct values (verified with is_string(), is_numeric(), strlen(), preg_match()... before the method insertData() is called)

Comment: I think your common sense means these lines `$values  .= $i != count($data) ? "'$val', " : "'$val'"; }` and where you insert values into query.

Comment: @Dlk, values are not added into the query. Columns are.

Comment: @raitxningu are you kidding? What on Earth does is string or strlen to do with SQL injections? And again, you cannot guarantee that all this useless stuff is indeed called. It is not mandatory, like a prepared statement, but entirely on the skill, temper, or mood if the user. And therefore, some day will leak